# What are the EJB Remote Interfaces in the project when createEJBStubs.bat is run?

Tags: batch-file, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I understand that createEJBstubs are necessary to create the stubs whenever it is accessed externally via. An Java Client (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rejb_3stubscmd2.html?lang=ko). And also, that the stubs that are created will be for the EJB3 interfaces that are available within the module. But how do they detect if a given interface/bean is of type EJB 3 and not 2.*. From the issue the I have faced below, it is not clear to me as to how this detection is done. Please help me to understand this so that I can resolve the issue that I am facing (below)-

**DETAILED EXPLANATION OF MY ISSUE:**
When I run `createEJBStubs.bat C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj.jar -updatefile C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj.jar -verbose`

I get the following error -

```
    CNTR9241I: The C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar Java archive (JAR) file has no level 3.0 enterprise beans with remote interfaces.
```

And when I run the same command using `-verbose` option, I get the following error -

```
createWarProcessingRootDir: enter
Root directory for war processing: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622
War explosion root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls
War primary input root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\primary
War primary classpath root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\primary\classPth
War primary workspace root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\primary\wrkSpace
War alternate workspace root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\alternate\wrkSpace
War alternate output file: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\alternateOutputWar.war
War embedded in ear root: C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\_tempWar_1096410607889881622\warExpls\embInEar
createWarProcessingRootDir: exit

Dumping input parameters:
        parameter 1 = C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNA
PSHOT.jar
        parameter 2 = -updatefile
        parameter 3 = C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNA
PSHOT.jar
        parameter 4 = -trace

Processing the C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar input file.

checkEJBVersion - jar name is C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar
The output file name is C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\ejb3093395338317385883.jar


copyArchiveEntriesAndStubs(null,C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar,C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\ejb3093395338317385883.jar,false)
Main output archive file (no pre-existing stubs) is C:\Users\w723521\AppData\Local\Temp\ejb3093395338317385883.jar
Preexisting stubs archive file is ejb5694574801473018226.jar

        Writing non-stub entry MANIFEST.MF
        Writing non-stub entry TestLocal.class
        Writing non-stub entry TestRemote.class

Classloader updated for -cp null
Classloader updated for jar C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar


getMetaData - entry
metadataComplete setting is false


findRemoteInterfaces
List of interfaces are: null
Number of pre-existing stubs = 0
CNTR9241I: The C:\1\DEN\proj\target\proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar Java archive (JAR) file has no level 3.0 enterprise beans with remote interfaces.
Starting process of deleting workspace files...
Done with process of deleting workspace files...
Command Successful
```

I am not able to understand why it says that no local and remote interfaces are of EJB3 even though the bean classes created using EJB3 annotations

```
@Remote
public interface TestRemote {
   public void test();
}

@Remote
public interface TestRemote {
   public void test();
}
```

**How does the script detect if a given interface is EJB3 or not?** (based on the output that I have obtained it is not as clear as I expected it to be)

Answer (score 0):

proj-5.DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar would need to somehow specify both an EJB and its remote interface.  For example, if ejb-jar.xml is used, a `<session>` with a `<remote>pkg.TestRemote</remote>`.  For another example, if some class in the JAR is annotated with `@Stateless` and `@Remote(TestRemote.class)`.

Comment: So, the even though the -trace option states that no "interfaces" are available, the actual issue is caused by the lack of the service bean in the same module? (the service bean is in a different module -- both the module that the EJB belongs to and the module that the interfaces belong to are placed under the same parent [maven] )

Comment: Yes.  It's been awhile since I was very familiar with the createEJBStubs command, but you can either try putting the interface JAR on the `-cp` path, or you can put the EJB module (with the service bean) and the interfaces in a single EAR (or WAR), but in any case, the primary JAR file needs to contain the service bean (or ejb-jar.xml with `metadata-complete="true"`).